# Debugging an HDMI-to-DisplayPort cable

Tags: hdmi, displayport

*Backstory: I've recently bought a new computer and monitor for my grandpa. When trying to set things up for him, I've encountered weird behavior with one of the cables.*

I have an HDMI-to-DisplayPort cable that doesn't seem to work. I have 2 different monitors to test, one of them has DisplayPort input only, the other DisplayPort and HDMI, and 3 different computers with an HDMI output (running Windows 10, ArchLinux, MacOS). When using the HDMI-to-DisplayPort cable, none of the computers recognize any of the two monitors to even exist (e.g. `xrandr` says `disconnected`).

If i use an HDMI cable to hook up the HDMI-capable monitor to the computer(s), it works out of the box in all three cases.

Am I correct to conclude that the cable ist just broken and I should return it to the store where I bought it, or is there something else I can try or some quirkyness about HDMI-to-DisplayPort adapters that I'm not aware of that can explain this behavior?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure it's an adapter to connect PC HDMI output to monitor DP input? Usually the adapters are used the other way around, connecting a DP to HDMI only monitor.

Comment: These standards are usually backwards compatible as in you can go from DP -> HMDI -> DVI, but not forwards.  To go in the other direction needs active electronics.